# Custom function in CSS content property

Tags: javascript, css, sass

i see some strange markup on some website:

```
body::before{
    content:"/map-to-JSON((mobile: 480px, tablet: 768px, desktop: 1200px))/"
}
```

What this mean? And how this work?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That is CSS, not markup.

It creates a [pesudo-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/#gen-content) before the `<body>` element and sets it's [content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#content-property) to the string you can see there.

i.e. it displays that text before the body.

It's pretty obvious if you just look at the results:

```css
body::before{
    content:"/map-to-JSON((mobile: 480px, tablet: 768px, desktop: 1200px))/"
}
```

Comment: Almost makes you wonder if there's more to it than meets the eye, though. I mean, that's a very strange string to be inserting using generated content - and in the body element, no less.

Comment: @BoltClock — It could be anything from a note the developer inserted to remind themselves of something, to the output from a debugging tool.